# Conditional visibility for a row that toggled with another textbox in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in ssrs like:

```
Name      Age
[Name]    [Age]
[Total]   sum([Total])
```

The [Name] row is toggled with Total, so When I click '+' sign near Total I can see each Name and Age, otherwise they are hidden. For some of my cases I have Age = 0 and I do not want to show them. I have to do this modification in SSRS, not in SQL. But since the row visibility settings are arranged for toggling (default:hidden) I cannot write expression there I guess. SO I could not find out what to do to provide this. I need something like:

For Hidden: `IIF(Fields!Age.Value > 0, false, true)`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to tablix properties, in the Filters tab add a filter:

[image]

Where I set `Point` use your field `Age`, select `>` operator and use `=0` expression in Value.

Now you can see use toogle functionality without zeroes values.

With the filter and without filter

[image] [image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! You are saving my life in my ssrs tasks all the time!